# How come this jQuery script will not highlight the first child in my list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <style>
    .emphasis { font-weight: bold; } 
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('li:first-child').addClass('emphasis');
    });
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>hello2</li>
    <li>hello3</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm following a tutorial: http://tutsplus.com/lesson/not-so-fast-jquery/

This code is exactly what he has near the end, yet it does not work for me. Any reason why?

Comment: [It works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/J754K/)

Comment: first-child supporting issues in cross-browser, use li:first instead.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: It shouldn't have cross-browser issues from the selector; I thought jQuery abstracted selectors by using [Sizzle](http://www.sizzlejs.com/).

Comment: @icktoofay: It for surely does use Sizzle. 100% sure of that infact, only issue is first-child doesn't work in IE6 or IE7. At least not on my machine. Don't know why..always wondered myself.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: `:first-child` works for me in IE 6, 7, 8, and 9.

Comment: the point is, it doesnt work for everyone, and it doesnt work for the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine. Try clearing your browsers cache or try it in a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

try using `$('li:first')` instead?